# How do I change the login screen in Arch linux?

Tags: command-line, arch-linux, kde5, sddm

Well, I currently installed Arch Linux with the Desktop Enviroment KDE Plasma 5. But I don`t like the Login screen, so I want to change it. I installed the display-manager sddm.

[image: Picture of current login screen]

Does anyone know how to change it? Any help is welcome.

Answer (score 2):

I went to system settings > Login Screen (SDDM). Then I installed a new SDDM theme and replaced the current theme.